# Query both first_name and last_name from wp_usermeta at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch both the first_name and last_name of all users at the same time, using the wpdb-object and the wp_usermeta table. I can't seem to figure out how to get both in the same query. Below is what I've got so far.

```
global $wpdb;
    $ansatte = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id, meta_value AS first_name FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='first_name'");

    foreach ($ansatte as $ansatte) {
        echo $ansatte->first_name;
    }
```

Using the above code I'm able to echo out the first names of all users, but i would like for the last_name to be available aswell, like so;

```
foreach ($ansatte as $ansatte) {
        echo $ansatte->first_name . ' ' $ansatte->last_name;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you must use raw SQL, which I advise against, don't hard code the table names, and use those provided by the `$wpdb` object, else you risk compatability issues across sites and multisite installs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find a clean, native way to pull this data. There are a couple of ways I can think of to do this: First, something like:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT user_id,meta_key,meta_value
  FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} 
  WHERE ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'first_name' OR {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'last_name')";
$ansatte = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
var_dump($sql);
$users = array();
foreach ($ansatte as $a) {
  $users[$a->user_id][$a->meta_key] = $a->meta_value;
}
var_dump($users);
```

You can then do:

```
foreach ($users as $u) {
    echo $u['first_name'].' '.$u['last_name'];
}
```

... to `echo` your user names.

The second way, a more pure SQL way, is what you were attempting:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id,{$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value as first_name,m2.meta_value as last_name
  FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} 
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} as m2 ON {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id = m2.user_id
  WHERE ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'first_name' 
  AND m2.meta_key = 'last_name')";
$ansatte = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($ansatte as $ansatte) {
  echo $ansatte->first_name . ' ' . $ansatte->last_name;
}
```

You could also use `get_users()` or `WP_User_Query` to pull users but the meta_data you want isn't in the data returned and it would take more work to retrieve it.

Comment: Doesn't it return all users with `fist_name = Me` AND `last_name = Myselfandi`?

Comment: Yes, it does. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: I didn't ask that question and I don't think that's what this question asks for. Please take a closer look at the question. I believe it's an interesting question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @sakibmoon

Comment: Thank you! So, if i remove those two values I'll be getting what I'm after? I've figured out an alternative solution, quering for the user_id and using get_user_meta($ansatte->user_id, 'first_name', true) and get_user_meta($ansatte->user_id, 'last_name', true) to fetch both names. But thats probably not ideal.

Comment: @s_ha_dum +1. Nice one. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is a straight MySQL pivot answer for phpMyAdmin assuming your Wordpress table prefix is "wp_";

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.user_email,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) AS first_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.meta_key = 'last_name' THEN meta_value END) AS last_name 
FROM wp_users AS t1 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.user_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.user_email;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct approach using just SQL:

```sql
SELECT id
     , (SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND meta_key = 'first_name') first_name
     , (SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND meta_key = 'last_name') last_name
  FROM wp_users
```

Here are approaches that don't work:

- JOIN once for each metadata field does not work because there is no UNIQUE key on wp_usermeta(user_id, meta_key)
- Using subquery SELECT without MAX fails because there is no UNIQUE key on wp_usermeta(user_id, meta_key)

And for some reason this is faster than using a single select and join.